# Solution to a problem

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance

I came across a question in a book titled "An introduction to Generalized Linear Models" which is given below

[image]

By adding $-\mu$ and + $\mu$, I found the solution to (b) as $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\mu)^2 + n(\bar Y - \mu )^2]$

The only difference is +. What do you think I am doing wrong?

Here is my work

[image]

Hint: $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i -\mu)=0$

Comment: The hint still is not correct, at least not with the conventional understanding that the $Y_i$ are drawn iid from a distribution with mean $\mu$, as stated in the problem. For instance, in the case $n=1$ there is no guarantee that $Y_1=\mu$.

Comment: I'd forget the hint (which is wrong) and work on simplifying what you have there a bit further.